# How can I find contours inside ROI using opencv and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, roi

Im trying to find contours in a specific area of the image. Is it possible to just show the contours inside the ROI and not the contours in the rest of the image? I read in another similar post that I should use a mask, but I dont think I used it correctly. Im new to openCV and Python, so any help is much appriciated.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('size4.avi')
x, y, w, h= 150, 50, 400 ,350
roi = (x, y, w, h)

while(True): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,    cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    roi = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
    mask = np.zeros(roi.shape,np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

    cv2.imshow('img', frame)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you claim to be a novice, I have worked out a solution along with an illustration.

Consider the following to be your original image:

[image]

Assume that the following region in red is your region of interest (ROI), where you would like to find your contours:

[image]

First, construct an image of black pixels of the same size. **It MUST BE OF SAME** size:

```
black = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), np.uint8) #---black in RGB
```

[image]

Now to form the mask and highlight the ROI:

```
black1 = cv2.rectangle(black,(185,13),(407,224),(255, 255, 255), -1)   #---the dimension of the ROI
gray = cv2.cvtColor(black,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)               #---converting to gray
ret,b_mask = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255, 0)                 #---converting to binary image
```

[image]

Now mask the image above with your original image:

```
fin = cv2.bitwise_and(th,th,mask = mask)
```

[image]

Now use `cv2.findContours()` to find contours in the image above.

Then use `cv2.drawContours()` to draw contours on the original image. You will finally obtain the following:

[image]

There might be better methods as well, but this was done so as to get you aware of the **bitwise AND**  operation availabe in OpenCV which is exclusively used for **masking**

Comment: I gave this solution because you wanted to know how to perform masking in an image. The key is to efficiently use the function `cv2.bitwise_and()`

Comment: Yes, it was a great way to understand how to mask, thanks ;) A small follow up question: when i draw the contours I also get a contour around the frame of the ROI as well as the contours inside, is that supposed to happend? I see you dont have it in your example.

Comment: That may happen if you have not inverted your image

Answer (score 6):

For setting a ROI in Python, one uses standard NumPy indexing [such as in this example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html).

So, to select the right ROI, you don't use the cv2.rectangle function (that is for drawing a rectangle), but you do this instead:

```
 _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)
 roi = thresh[x:(x+w), y:(y+h)]
 im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(roi, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: You can pass to `findContours` the offset of the rectangle, so that the retrieved contour points are referred to the original image

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I changed the way I wrote the roi. How would I offset the rectangle like you suggest Miki?

Comment: The docs: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours say the last argument of the function is a tuple that specifies the offset; i.e.: `im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(roi, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, (x, y))`