# How to apply threshold counters to only specified/masking region in the image using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, pycharm

I am new in OpenCV and stuck at a point actually, I study lots of QA but all are unable or I can say not fully satisfied my requirement. 
Suppose I have an image and I want to find counters for objectifying specified area only.
It is easy to counter a complete image but I want to counters only masking area.

For masking purpose I have x,y coordinates with me.
So my question is how to counter only masking area in the image using OpenCV

This is the one solution matching with my question->[Stackoverflow suggestion -:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004652/how-can-i-find-contours-inside-roi-using-opencv-and-python)
 But it does not solving my problem completely.
The given solution in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004652/how-can-i-find-contours-inside-roi-using-opencv-and-python) is quite complicated and not solving my problem. as I want my counters ROI to be show in the same image using mask coordinates(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax).
Means i first drawing reactangle mask into the image and i want to draw counters boundary only into that rectangle mask in the same image.

This is my Demo.py file:-

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("F:/mycar.jpg",1)
crop_img = cv2.rectangle(img, (631,181), (698,386), (0,255,0), 3)
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 127, 255, 0)
img_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, img_contours, -1, (255, 0, 0))
cv2.imshow("dflj",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output

[image]

From this image, you can see that the complete image is countering.
But I want to just counter only that green-rectangle part of the image.

Means that blue counter boundary lines is visible inside whole image but I  want to show only it inside of green-rectangle box.

I have rectangle coordinates with me (eg. minx-631, miny-181, maxx-698,  maxy-386).
Please help.

Comment: You can extract that specific part of the image using ROI and then you can find contours in that region.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find contours inside ROI using opencv and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004652/how-can-i-find-contours-inside-roi-using-opencv-and-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply functions to ROIs using Numpy indexing as explained in [this tutoral](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html):

```
top,left = 338,282
h,w = 216,106

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
crop_img = cv2.rectangle(img, (left,top), (left+w,top+h), (0,255,0), 3)

retval, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 127, 255, 0)
img_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh[top:top+h,left:left+w], cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img[top:top+h,left:left+w], img_contours, -1, (255, 0, 0))
```

Please note that **with Numpy indexing y comes first then x**, as opposed to point coordinates with (x,y).

With [this image](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/07/04/13/41/auto-383897_960_720.jpg) we get:[image]

Comment: yup... It's working.  Thank you very much@Stef. Your solution will help other peoples too, who stuck like me.... keep doing it, great job